# Visio 2010 DataSources not showing in reverse engineer wizard

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, visio, windows-7-x64

Hi I am trying to do a database diagram in visio 2010 to existing database. I am using the reverse engineer wizard. When I push new button on datasource field. I follow the steps to add new datasource. It looks like everything worked no errors, tested connection and it passes. But after finishing the process it should add it to the datasource box so I can select and proceed on. But it does not show up. DataSource is still blank.

Specifics: It is a 2008 R2 Express db trying to connect to using visio 2010. OS is Window 7 64bit.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similiar problem when creating the datasource as "file data source". Once I created it as user or system datasource it showed up. (Using Visio 2010 on WinXp connecting to SQL-server 2008)

Comment: It now shows up for me, but when I click next and enter the username/password, Visio aborts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's really odd but it seems that using Generic OLE DB driver works for this issue.

Comment: Weird indeed. I have the same issue. I think it's because of user restrictions on a workstation. (Currently I'm in a overly controlled network environment and I'm assuming that's why it didn't work as expected)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, here is how I resolved it:

1. Beside Installed Visio drivers selected, MS SQL Server, at the bottom of the list, checked SQL Server Native 10.0
2. Under Data Sources, clicked on new, (I used User Data Source), then on the Create New Data Source Screen, used SQL Server Native 10.0

Upon completing the wizard, my data source did appear.

The main thing is to have SQL Server 10.0 checked beside on the Microsoft SQL Server option (not checked by default)